# Using environment variables from docker-compose.yml in Angular app

Tags: angular, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have **enviroment.prod.ts** file in my Angular app

```
export const environment = {
  backendUrl: '127.0.0.1:3000',
};
```

And this is a part of **docker-compose.prod.yml**:

```
....
environment:
      - ENV_BACKEND_URI=127.0.0.1:3000
....
```

How can I set `backendUrl` using `ENV_BACKEND_URI` from **docker-compose.prod.yml**?
I want something like that:

```
export const environment = {
      backendUrl: '${ENV_BACKEND_URI}',
    };
```

Is this posible?

Comment: Have you tried to access ENV_BACKEND_URI, from the process.env.ENV_BACKEND_URI?

Comment: Yes, and build fails with "Cannot find name 'process'"

Answer (score 7):

Yes - it is possible, even though Angular runs on the client's environment, it still runs build steps on the environment it is deployed on.

Generally the `envsubst` program can be used to feed environment variables into a file. So with your above example of an `environment.ts` file:

```
export const environment = {
      backendUrl: '${ENV_BACKEND_URI}',
    };
```

If we were to name it `src/environments/environment.template.ts`, the command

```
envsubst < src/environments/environment.template.ts > src/environments/environment.ts
```

will produce an `environments.ts file as desired, with ${ENV_BACKEND_URI} replaced as per environment variables.

Don't forget to have your Dockerfile install it in your docker image (using the appropriate package installer method listed  [here](https://command-not-found.com/envsubst))

This command needs to be run as `docker-compose up` starts the container, so that it will have access to the environment variables injected into the container spawned by docker-compose.

This can be acheived in a couple of ways:

1. Replace the `ng serve` usually command used to start Angular (either as `CMD` in your Dockerfile, or `command` in the `docker-compose.yml` dockerfile with

```
envsubst < src/environments/environment.template.ts > src/environments/environment.ts && ng serve
```

or

2. Instead of `ng serve` run `npm run start` as the docker command. This will run the `start` script in your `package.json` (which by default is `ng serve`), but will run anything in a "prestart" script first. So edit `package.json` to contain:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "envsubst < src/environments/environment.template.ts > src/environments/environment.ts",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from where should your system environment content comes?

Your angular app get's shipped to the user via whatever webserver, there is no node.js process or something else which could offer you a server environment variable.

consider the environment.ts in angular as a built time one-way collection of flags.

The only way to change things afterwards the app is shipped goes to api calls.

So setup a secure way to maybe request GET /api/config maybe with a one way startup token or whatever could be secure.

Comment: My app is built inside docker container. And as far as I know I can set environment variables in docker-compose.prod.yml file, and after that I want to pass those variables to dockerfile where I run ng build command

Comment: Thats all fine, but your angular app is only shipped and will not be executed on the server, so you do not have access to system env variables. The app get's executed on the browser on the client.

Comment: Aren't those variables values saved to code in bundle while building?

Comment: Is there a way to set a variable in docker.compose.yml and then pass it to js bundle while building an app

Comment: maybe with that way: https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659 but not directly